# Can you input decimals number in smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, web3js

I'm having an issue where send 0.1 or 1.1 is saved as 0 and 1 in my contract's storage.

Does anyone knows how to properly pass decimals ?

Comment: No, there are no fixed-point numbers in Solidity. See [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83785/24693).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating-point or fixed-point decimals have not yet been implemented in Solidity.

If you want, for example, 10 decimal places of precision you can just multiply all inputs by 10^10.

In this case, you would input `0.1e10` or `1.1e10` respectively, then when you fetch them you can just divide by `1e10`

Comment: What about negative int -1 ?

Comment: negatives should still work, just use `int` instead of `uint`

Comment: Wouldn't dividing by 1e10 just chop off everything that's past the decimal anyway?

Comment: You would only do the division when displaying the value to the end user, in which case you would be using a language with floating point support like JS