# What fixed or float point math libraries are available in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, floating-point

Solidity doesn't have fixed-point, floating-point, or double types. What solutions are there to handle the cases where we really have to represent numbers as percentages or fractions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am the author of PRBMath.

### Fixed-Point

1. [PRBMath](https://github.com/hifi-finance/prb-math/tree/v1.0.3)

   - signed and unsigned denary numbers with 18 decimals of precisions
   - offers advanced math functions (logs, exp, pow, etc.)
   - provides type safety via user defined value types
   - gas efficient, but still user-friendly
   - ergonomic developer experience thanks to using free functions instead of libraries
2. [ABDKMath64x64](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.md)

   - binary numbers with 2^64 precision
   - offers advanced math functions (logs, exp, pow, etc.)
   - ultra gas efficient (see this [praise](https://medium.com/hackernoon/10x-better-fixed-point-math-in-solidity-32441fd25d43))
3. [Fixidity](https://github.com/CementDAO/Fixidity)

   - denary numbers with arbitrary number of decimals
   - offers advanced math functions (logs, exp, pow, etc.)
   - slower than 64.64, but with a more palatable API
   - used by CementDAO, PoolTogether and Celo
4. [Exponential](https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/blob/v2.8.1/contracts/Exponential.sol)

   - denary numbers with 18 decimals of precision
   - minimal features, doesn't offer advanced math functions
   - developed by [Compound.Finance](https://compound.finance)
5. [DecimalMath](https://github.com/albertocuestacanada/DecimalMath)

   - denary numbers with 27 decimals of precision
   - minimal features, doesn't offer advanced math functions
   - uses ABIEncoderV2 (experimental in Solidity 0.7 and below)
6. [DSMath](https://github.com/dapphub/ds-math)

   - denary numbers with 18 (WAD) and 27 decimals of precision (RAY)
   - minimal features, doesn't offer advanced math functions
   - developed by the [DappHub](https://dapphub.com/) team, used by the [Maker](http://makerdao.com/) protocol

### Floating-Point

1. [ABDKMathQuad](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/v3.0/ABDKMathQuad.sol)

   - developed by the same company as 64.64
2. [Bankex](https://github.com/BankEx/solidity-float-point-calculation)

   - IEEE-754 octuple precision floating-point

### Addenda

1. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/409) in the solidity repo for adding native support for fixed-point types
2. Mikhail Vladimirov's [Math in Solidity](https://medium.com/coinmonks/math-in-solidity-part-1-numbers-384c8377f26d) blog series is a fantastic resource to learn about how advanced math functions can be implemented in Solidity v0.6 and lower
3. There are more math libraries mentioned in this [OpenZeppelin forum post](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/list-of-solidity-libraries-in-the-wild/2250)

Comment: You forgot the simplest (and most accurate) method: maintain a tuple of numerator and denominator, and in every computation, avoid division for as long as possible (i.e., use it only in order to avoid an overflow).

Comment: That's true, but I'd argue that the simplest approach to fixed-point math in solidity is also the brittlest.

Comment: I had to google-translate `brittlest`, which gave me: `having hardness and rigidity but little tensile strength`. Now I have to google-translate pretty much every one of the words in that...

Comment: Hah, what I meant is, I wouldn't encourage a simple approach when dealing with fixed-points. There's always something that could go wrong, and I'd rather rely on other more robust contracts (and tests!) that people wrote before me.