# I want to store decimal value in a storage variable and later use that variable at same precision in the formula later internally

Tags: solidity, remix, safemath, decimals

I want to store uint public MINTING_VELOCITY = 0.000002;

And later use it in the formula:  A x t x MINTING_VELOCITY ,where A = 2000 ,t(staking_duration_time) = 120

Issue is currently MINTING_VELOCITY is reading  0.

How to take the exact/fetch the decimal value with exact precision?Please follow the code shared in the screenshot to understand the scenario better[image]

How to achieve that via solidity .Please help!

Comment: Does this help you? [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity)

Comment: yes thanks.though my case is bit different here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use cast to integer arithmetic:

```
MINTING_VELOCITY = 2
ACCURACY_RATIO = 1000000
```

And the formula converts to: `A x t x MINTING_VELOCITY / ACCURACY_RATIO`

Comment: it wont work.Please look into the code snipped that I have just shared.Thanks

Comment: it actually helped me partially.Thanks man!