# Is it possible to have 0% buy fee on DEX and 5% fee on Sell DEX and also when token is transfer?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, openzeppelin

Token Tokenomics will be like this:
Buy: 0%
Sell/Transfer: 5%
and 5% goes to charity address.
This is the token contract:https://bscscan.com/address/0xfe03a2004648886987cf4b8fd433b1b132740121#code
This token already applied the 0 buy fee and 5% fee on sell, but the missing puzzle is the fee for transferring token from one address to another. Any help or advice willbe a big help.

Comment: You may need to use a [fixed-point math library](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83785/24693). See [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
function _transfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        uint256 senderBalance = _balances[sender];
        require(senderBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");

        unchecked {
            _balances[sender] = senderBalance.sub(amount);
        }
        
        bool takeFee = true;
        if (_isExcludedFromFee[sender]) {
            takeFee = false;
        }
        if(sender == pairAddress || !takeFee){ //checks if the sender is the uniswap pair or if its excluded from fees, doesnt take any fees if one of these conditions are true.
            _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
            emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        }
        else { // takes the fees normally otherwise
            uint256 taxFee = amount.mul(dexTaxFee).div(10000);
            _balances[taxAddress] = _balances[taxAddress].add(taxFee);
            emit Transfer(sender, taxAddress, taxFee);
            amount = amount.sub(taxFee);
            _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
            emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi @Foxxxey, does changing the `transfer()` function break the ERC20 convention? Will you still be able to add your token to Dex after that?

Comment: It doesn't break the spec in itself, but it makes it so when you're transferring tokens, the amount received is less than the amount sent, which can certainly break some contracts. For example, uniswap v2 supports that but uniswap v3 doesnt (well, the router doesnt).

Comment: ok thanks for the specification, so depends on dex, and need to check manually where it will break.