# Decimal in Solidity

Tags: solidity, decimals

I'm new to solidity but I program in other languages, solidity looks a bit like javascript but recently I noticed a problem with solidity.

it doesn't accept decimals and float numbers, like "0.001", how can I put this value in a variable?

I already tried to do:

> (1 * 1/1000) = 0.001

But there's an error I don't know about:

> Type rational_const 1 / 1000 is not implicitly convertible to expected
> type uint256. Try converting to type ufixed8x3 or use an explicit
> conversion.

Comment: Related: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity).

Answer (score 2):

Solidity doesn't really support decimal numbers, so you shouldn't try to use them. You should simply use integers.

However, decimal numbers can be used if they are not assigned to. So something like `uint a = 1/3 * 6` should work.

Typically, at least for tokens, the used numbers are big enough that no real decimal places are needed. In the case of tokens, there is a different *display amount* which is shown in user interfaces, but that's not the amount used in the contracts.

Comment: i need to do something like: bnb/price = returns amount of tokens.

for example: 1 bnb / price per token = quantity of tokens.

Comment: 1 BNB is actually 1e8 jagers (https://academy.binance.com/en/glossary/jager). That amount is big enough to perform division on. So "1 BNB" is never `1` in contracts, but it's `1e8`

Answer (score 1):

Solidity doesnt support decimal numbers thats why each token has their own decimal value as an erc20 or bep20 standard

1 eth for example has 18 decimals
So you would write it as 1e18

As per your comment regarding bnb/price = num of tokens
If youre calculating that for a swap on pancakeswap then you should call pancakeswap router function getAmountsOut which when supplied with correct paramters should return how many tokens out you get for the bnb you input

If not then lets say you set the price to be 2 bnb
Supposing 1 bnb has 8 decimals the formula would be
100000000/200000000
= 1/2 = invalid for solidity
But this is where decimals for tokens come in , if your token youre trying to get the number of has a decimal of 9
Then the number of tokens would be
1/2 * 1000000000.
That is equal to half a token
You can think of decimals as keeping count of cents for the dollar
A dollar has two cent digits
If you want to get 3 dollars in solidity its wrote as 3 * 10 ** 2
So 300 cents.

Its important to note when youre doing the calculating
(Bnb / price)*decimalsOfToken = tokens out
This is incorrect because you will get a decimal value before multiplying with decimalsOfToken which is invalid so the solution is to multiply bnb with decimalsOfToken and then dividing by price

Comment: It is for a sales contract, I need to find out what would be "1 BNB / Price = amount of tokens for the user".  Maybe I need to make a rate, but I can't figure out how to make it using a price of 0.001. In my mind I could make 1 BNB / 0.001 = 1000 tokens.

Comment: I edited my answer hope this helps

Comment: The rate youre talking about should be the decimals of the token you want to calculate the number for based on price.