# Transactional fee question

Tags: contract-development

Is it possible to create a token contract that pays a tiny transaction fee in the ERC20 token to a third party? For example, if a person buys a token with .004 eth, is it possible to add an additional fee of 2% of that eth for their purchase? So when they buy that token for .004 eth,  that .00008 eth is sent to a third party account.

Thank u to any one who can help

Comment: Totally possible. Look at how [USDT](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7) implemented fees.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you happen to know some code for the smart contract for implementing a 2% eth fee when someone buys a token. If not it ok, but I was wondering.

Comment: I don't know. But for proportions and percentages, you may need a fixed-point math library. Check out [PRBMath](https://github.com/hifi-finance-prb-math) and my thread on the topic: [What fixed or float-point math libraries are available in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity)