# Attempting to calculate a majority vote

Tags: floating-point

I am trying to create a small voting system in a smart contract where a vote is passed when the majority of admins have voted. I now realise that this is not as easy as I thought, as there are no floats in Solidity, so I cannot simply do `(voteCount/adminCount)*100 > 50`. I noticed the problem when I tried to do `(2/3)*100` and it results in `0`.

How is something like this usually solved? Didn't pay much attention in math classes back in school, so the Google searches I've done on the topic didn't help me much.

Comment: You can multiply both side by `adminCount`.

Comment: what is `voteCount` (the count of all votes) ? I don't understand why voteCount could be lower than adminCount

Comment: Related: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity).

Answer (score 1):

Do first the multiplications and then divide:
 `(voteCount*100/adminCount) > 50`

In the case of  2 votes and 3 admins you will get `200/3 = 66 > 50`

If you need more resolution (decimals) you can add a multiplier to both side of the inequality, for instance:

`decimals: 2;`

`(voteCount*100*(10**decimals)/adminCount) > 50*(10**decimals)`

Again in the case of 2 out of 3 votes you will get `20000/3 = 6666 > 5000`

Hope this helps