# I cannot divide these two values together in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, bug, dapp-debugging

```
  function calculate(
   uint index
       )public view returns(uint, uint, bool){
   uint avh1;
   uint avh2;
   uint avh3;
   uint avl1;
   uint avl2;
   uint avl3;
  
   uint allowbuy;
   uint allowsell;
           //function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        //   return a + b;
           priceHistory memory coinToReturn = stableCoins[index];
           
           avh1 = coinToReturn.highestPricethismonth.add (coinToReturn.highestPrice2MonthsAgo);
           avh2 = coinToReturn.highestPrice3MonthsAgo.add (coinToReturn.highestPrice4MonthsAgo);
           avh3 = avh1.add (avh2); avh3/4= allowsell;
           avl1 = coinToReturn.lowestPricethismonth.add (coinToReturn.lowestPrice2MonthsAgo);
           avl2 = coinToReturn.lowestPrice3MonthsAgo.add (coinToReturn.lowestPrice4MonthsAgo);
           avl3 = avl1.add (avl2); avl3.div  (4)  = allowbuy;
           
           
          return (allowbuy);
          return (allowsell);
          return (success);
        
        }
```

on the lines where I end up dividing, no matter the methods i use to divide  I keep getting the same error message, "expression has to be an 1value"

Comment: Not a direct answer but you may want to use a fixed-point math library to simplify your code: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity)

Comment: Also you may want to use a code formatter such as Prettier. See my [solidity-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template) boilerplate which bundles up a Prettier plugin for Solidity, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

These are not valid solidity code

```
avh3/4= allowsell;

...

avl3.div  (4)  = allowbuy;
```

To assign the result to the varibales you have to swap left and right

```
allowsell = avh3/4;

...

allowbuy = avl3.div(4);
```