# Multiply number with Pi in solidity

Tags: solidity, math, safemath

I'm finding a library to implement this formula in solidity.[image]

Is there is a library to implement this formula.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PRBMath](https://github.com/hifi-finance/prb-math/tree/6d849c97831550e521a4bb363bb82eb78bb0415b/packages/prb-math)!

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity >=0.8.4;

import "prb-math/contracts/PRBMathSD59x18.sol";

contract SignedConsumer {
  using PRBMathSD59x18 for int256;

  /// @notice Calculates x*PI÷1e18 while handling possible intermediary overflow.  function multiplyByPi(int256 x) external pure returns (int256 result) {
    int256 pi = PRBMathSD59x18.pi();
    result = x.mul(pi);
  }
}
```

P.S. see my comparison of fixed-point math libraries for Solidity: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity)