# 0x Handling of tokens with less than 18 decimals

Tags: 0x

I am trying to create a sell limit order with an 18 decimal ERC20 token as makerToken (makerAmount = 1.5) and a 6 decimal ERC20 token as takerToken (takerAmount 1.1). The order is created but remainingFillableTakerAmount returned from the API shows zero. I would have expected it to be equal to takerAmount. Doesn't seem to be a problem when both maker and taker token have 18 decimals. Is there some special logic that I should consider?

Thanks for your help in advance

[image]

Comment: You might need to use a [fixed-point math library](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity). I recommend [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with conversions. This must be a problem on the 0x side as remainingFillableTakerAmount is not something you pass on when signing an order. I reported this same issue back in December already. Here the conversation link: https://discord.com/channels/435912040142602260/435912040142602262/922648296755974194

Answer (score 2):

Do you definitely have the allowance on the `makerToken` set correctly? Can you post a fresh order in the question as text?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that a missing allowance caused this problem. 0x seems to perform an allowance check on their end and if it's insufficient, `remainingFillableTakerAmount` is set to 0.