# Dealing with tokens with different decimals in wei

Tags: solidity

I have two tokens, `tokenA` which has a decimal value of `18` and `tokenB` with `9` decimals. I would like to buy `tokenB` for `tokenA` or vica-versa. The question is that do I need to make any conversions with the wei values because the different decimals in Solidity? I know that decimals are important when we convert from wei to ether for instance, but if I keep both token amounts in wei, I assume the below calculation will be correct without managing the two `amount` variable differently.

```
// calculating the output amount of DAI for X ETH
address[] memory path;
path[0] = token18Dec; // ETH
path[1] = token9Dec; // DAI token with 9 decimals
amounts = uniswapRouter.getAmountsOut(ethBudget, path)[1];

// calculating the output amount of ETH for X DAI
address[] memory path;
path[0] = token9Dec; // ETH
path[1] = token18Dec; // DAI token with 9 decimals
amounts = uniswapRouter.getAmountsOut(daiTokenBalance, path)[1];
```

Comment: You might need a fixed-point math library. See this: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity). And see my math library [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should convert both to the Wei as solidity by default deals any integer as in Wei