# Why are protocols like Sushiswap using multiplier 1e10 instead of 1e18?

Tags: solidity, math

I've been reviewing a protocol that utilizes MULTIPLIER for their calculations which increases the precision because there are no decimal numbers in solidity. That is fine, but I've seen a lot of protocols using MULTIPLIER 1e10, so 10^10.

This makes no sense to me. Everything in solidity is in wei 10^18. So if we want to calculate, let's say 2 ether times 3 ether, we want the result to be 6 ether. So logically, the multiplier should be 10^18 like this:

`(2 ether * 3 ether) / 1e18 = 6 * 10^18 or 6 ether`

If we use only 1e10 the result isn't correct in this case:

`(2 ether * 3 ether) / 1e10 = 6 * 10^26 or 600000000 ether`

This works both with multiplying and dividing numbers:

`(10 ether * 1e18) / 2 ether = 5 ether or 5 * 10^18`

But if we used 1e10, it wouldn't work:

`(10 ether * 1e10) / 2 ether = 5 * 10^10 or 50000000000`

So either I'm missing something big, or it doesn't make sense.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: What number of decimals to use for an ERC-20 token or a DeFi protocol is a pretty arbitrary decision.

Comment: Potentially related: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity)

Answer (score 0):

this should be for pairs that have 8 decimals, to increase them to 18