# What is the most efficient way of coding a compounding inflationary function for an ERC-20 token?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I'm programming an `inflate()` function for an inflationary token.

Currently using a very inefficient for loop. What is a better way? Should I assembly or maybe exponents? Code & links to relevant contracts appreciated!

Current code:

```
    uint last =      // the last time inflation was calculated 

    uint frequency = // frequency (seconds) to compound inflation

    uint inflation = // amount to inflate per frequency

    uint multiple =  // what [inflation] was multiplied by to make it a whole number

    uint current = block.timestamp;

    uint intervals = (current - last) /  frequency; 
    
    uint newInflation = totalSupply;

    for (uint i; i < intervals; ++i) {
        newInflation += newInflation * inflation / multiple;
    }

    newInflation -= totalSupply;
```

Comment: You may need a [fixed-point math library](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83785/24693). See [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Comment: Thankyou @PaulRazvanBerg — definitely needed a fixed-point math library!

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way would be to use an collector / index variable and inflate in continous time.
For example the balance after 1 month would be:

```
balance = initial adjusted balance * growth index
```

, where

```
initial adjusted balance = adjusted balance / growth index
```

The [Aave](https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/d1876f3824e6773343e5be7df5f9ccca34b25f29/contracts/protocol/tokenization/base/ScaledBalanceTokenBase.sol) or [Compound](https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/blob/master/contracts/CToken.sol) repository could be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Though this equation this doesn't compound. Should've been clearer in the question. — editing now. Will check the contracts!

Comment: You would compound the index variable.