# How do I remove decimals from a uint256

Tags: solidity, uint256, math, decimals

I am calculating a `buyPrice` that has a factor of 1.2 times the normal price.

To do this I get the token price and multiply it by `1200000000000000000` (18). It looks something like:

```
uint256 buyPrice = get18DecimalPrice() * 18DecimalBuyMultiplier;
```

This works, but it leaves me with a 36 decimal integer. I need it to be 18 decimals for further calculations. How can I slice off the last 18?

I am aware that when you divide a 36 decimal uint with an 18 decimal uint, the result is an 18 decimal uint. I'm just not sure what to do to achieve such a result in this case.

EDIT: Thanks to Paul Razvan Berg I started using PRBMath, which does not produce the same problem. I am still looking for an answer to the question as I am curious about how these math libraries handle the problem laid out in the question.

Comment: You may need to use a [fixed-point math library](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83785/24693). See [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg This worked, thank you. I would still like to know *how* it is able to remove the last 18 decimals, or even if it approaches this method in another way.

Comment: No worries. Reading the README of the PRBMath should automatically answer this question for you. But in short, the idea is that you divide by 1e18 after you make the multiplication.