# How to write a linear formula for percentage in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, math, safemath, algorithm

So id like to write this function in solidity but im having issues because of the integers not being accepted.
s being the startin time. Lets say 1 second in unix time.
x being the ending time. Lets say 1 weeks worth of unix time.
Any idea on how i could put this into code and see it work?

```
f(x) = (0.8 / s + 1 - e)* (x - s - 1) + 0.8
```

The whole idea behind is that id like to calculate a fee, based on the time passed after a certain timestamp. Id like it to start at 80% and end in 0% after a week. In other words when the subtraction of the current block.timestamp - the stored one is >= than 1 weeks it becomes 0.

Comment: What is the `e` supposed to be?

Comment: You may need to use a [fixed-point math library](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83785/24693). See [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Answer (score 2):

To represent decimal numbers, you can use integers and assumes that the first couple of digits are used as decimal places.

It is common to use 18 decimal places. When working with fixed-point numbers, it is advisable to use a math library such as [prb math](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).