# How would you write this function in Solidity ? I keep getting error because of the floats

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, math, remix-tests, safemath

```
function calcPercentage(int elapsedTime){
    return round(8000 + (elapsedTime * (100/36))/10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solidity does not support floating point math operations. For that, you would need to create your own logic to work on integers and treat a part of them as the whole number and another part of them as the decimals. But that could be combersome.

You can better reuse a library that already solves that, like the [prb-math](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math/tree/v1.0.3) library, [abdk-libraries-solidity](https://v), etc.

There's a detailed answer that shows many common implementations. Feel free to take a look: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity)