# I dont understand how to use ABDKMath64x64 for mul and div

Tags: solidity, decimals

If i console.log this
`ABDKMath64x64.add(3, 2);`

I get the result of `BigNumber { value: "5" }` which is correct.

But
`ABDKMath64x64.mul(3, 2);`
returns `BigNumber { value: "0" }`

and
`ABDKMath64x64.div(3, 2);`
returns `BigNumber { value: "27670116110564327424" }`

Why i cant get 6 for `.mul` and 1.5 for `div`? What am i missing?

Comment: ABDKMath uses binary numbers. If you don't like them, consider switching to a fixed-point math library that uses decimal numbers, such as [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math). Also consider reading this thread: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83785/24693)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABDKMath64x64 are math library for fixed-point numbers.

So "3" and "2" are not decimal "3" and "2".

For ABDKMath64x64 first 64bit are integer part and next 64bit are fractional part.

So Integer `3` are `0x00000000000000030000000000000000` for fixed point.

You can try `ABDKMath64x64.mul(0x30000000000000000, 0x20000000000000000);` returns `0x00000000000000060000000000000000`