# How to calculate virtual (50/50 & x*y=k) reserves of UniSwap V3 Pair?

Tags: dapps, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, cryptoeconomics

I know how to get balances of each token from a pair, and if I'm not mistaken - those balances of tokens is indeed a real reserves.
Also, L is stored in contract info, but I doubt one thing - this L is just an L or L^2 or a srqt(L).
From sqrtRatioX96 price can be founded.

Found, that
(x(real) + L / sqrt(Pb))*(y(real) + L * sqrt(Pa)) = L**2

As well as

(x(real) + x(virtual)) * (y(real) + y(virtual)) = L**2

So
x(virtual) = L / sqrt(Pb)
y(virtual) = L * sqrt(Pa)
But what (Pa) & (Pb) is exactly? P(a) is a token0Price & (Pb) is a token1Price? Or (Pa) & (Pb) is a high & low price of this tick/ concentration zone. I have thoughts that (Pa) & (Pb) is a "price range" of current tick/position, but no clue how to find this (Pa) & (Pb).
If Pa = token0Price (from sqrtRatioX96) & If Pb = token1Price (from sqrtRatioX96)
I've got:
x(virtual) = L / sqrt(token0Price)
x(virtual) = 776218541774739337116335 / sqrt(0.0008191556417896165)
x(virtual) = 776218541774739337116335 / 0.02862089519
x(virtual) = 2.7120694046143822e+25
x(virtual) = 27120694046143822000000000 (18 decimal)

y(virtual) = L * sqrt(P)
y(virtual) = 776218541774739337116335 * sqrt(1220.7692274636495)
y(virtual) = 776218541774739337116335 * 34.9395081171
y(virtual) = 2.7120694040982028e+25
y(virtual) = 27120694040982028000000000 (18 decimal)

x(virtual) (token0Price) = 27120694046143822000000000 = 27120694.046143822
y(virtual) (token1Price) = 27120694040982028000000000

Yeah, look's pretty 50/50, but what exactly those numbers is?
That's a DAI/WETH pair (0,5 fee) and if that's a "USD valued" reserves - not possible, because real reserves of DAI at that moment was 2591437.269710515203595384 & 2838.497576725882781612 of WETH.

Is there anything that i missed?

Comment: You might need a fixed-point math library in order to do this. See [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math) and this thread: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity).

Answer (score 1):

From https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf

```
(x(real) + L / sqrt(Pb))*(y(real) + L * sqrt(Pa)) = L**2:
x_virtual = L / sqrt(Pb) & y_virtual = L * sqrt(Pa)

At the momment
L = 629666507025852065455329
DAI Reserves (balanceOf) 1319679676310680369741279
WETH Reserves (balanceOf) 3660663192506322781740


x_virtual =(629666507025852065455329/sqrt(1128.50448824))
x_virtual = (629666507025852065455329/33.5932208673)
x_virtual = 1.8743856372485445e+22
x_virtual = 18743856372485445000000
x_virtual = 18743.856372485445 


y_virtual = 629666507025852065455329 * sqrt(0.0008861285))
y_virtual = (629666507025852065455329 * 0.02976791057)
y_virtual = 1.8743856270069843e+22
y_virtual = 18743856270069843000000 
y_virtual = 18743.856270069843

x_virtual = 18743856372485445000000
y_virtual = 18743856270069843000000
```

0x60594a405d53811d3BC4766596EFD80fd545A270 - just in case you need to see which pair I'm using

That's right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your second formula is not correct, meaning that the rest of the computation is probably wrong, too. `P_a` is the low price of the tick range (or of the position, depending on the context). `P_b` is the high price of the range (position).

If you have a tick range from tick_A to tick_B then:

```
P_a = 1.0001 ^ tick_A
P_b = 1.0001 ^ tick_B
```

Then once you know the `P_a` and `P_b`, you can compute the virtual amount of assets using Equation 2.2 from the [Uniswap v3 whitepaper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf):

```
x_virtual = x_real + L / sqrt(P_b)
y_virtual = y_real + L * sqrt(P_a)
```

Comment: Hi! 
{x_virtual = x_real + L / sqrt(P_b)
y_virtual = y_real + L * sqrt(P_a)} seems to be incorrect

Comment: About the Pa & Pb:
  slot(0)
sqrtPriceX96   uint160 :  2358490336287291322714092334
  tick   int24 :  -70290
  observationIndex   uint16 :  29
  observationCardinality   uint16 :  180
  observationCardinalityNext   uint16 :  180
  feeProtocol   uint8 :  0
  unlocked   bool :  true

Comment: tick_A = -70290 & tick_B = 70290                                         .                  
Pa = 1.0001 ^ tick_A = 1.0001 ^ (-70290) = 0.0008861285                      

Pb = 1.0001 ^ tick_B = 1.0001 ^ 70290 = 1128.50448824