# Can I use a floating point number in solidity?

Tags: solidity

in this contract will the floating point work,

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0


contract AB {

   address payable  b= payable(xx);

    uint amount= 0.1 ether;
  


     function Optimizer( uint256 _amount )public  payable{

        
     _amount=msg.value;
        
       require(amount >=0.1 ether,"transfer amount to low");

      

      b.transfer(msg.value);

      
       
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you used the `ether` keyword with a floating point correctly. In Remix your `0.1 ether` line didn't cause any warnings or errors.

If you create a test function that returns `0.1 ether`, you can see that it really returns `100000000000000000`:

```js
function test() public pure returns(uint){

    return 0.1 ether;
    }
```

[image]

If you put this WEI value into an [Ethereum unit converter](https://eth-converter.com/), you can see the number's equivalent in GWEI and ETH:

[image]

A more refined version of your contract that uses `msg.value` correctly as opposed to your `_amount` uint, custom errors as opposed to your hard-coded require, and `call` instead of `transfer` for sending the ETH:

```js
contract AB {

  error CallFailed();
  error TransferAmountTooLow();

    uint amount= 0.1 ether;
    address payable b = payable(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2);


     function Optimizer( )public  payable{ 
      if(msg.value < 0.1 ether) {
        revert TransferAmountTooLow();
      }
      (bool sent,) = b.call{value: msg.value}("");
      if(!sent) {
        revert CallFailed();
      }    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: will it be okey on the mainnet, i mean with real funds & will it transfer 0.1 eth to specific address?

Comment: @stofu if you can compile and deploy the contract on a testnet/locally, it will compile and deploy on mainnet in the same way, so yes.

Comment: i deploy the contract on test net but its not sending eth and its also no meeting the condition of require(amount >=0.1 ether,"transfer amount to low");

Comment: @stofu can you provide the contract address and the name of the testnet you deployed it on? Also what input are you sending along with the function call? If you deployed your contact exactly as it is in your question, then there are a couple of reasons why it wouldn't work, for example `payable(xx)` and `_amount = msg.value`

Comment: goril, input:0.4 as a parameter in optimizer function. its the same error if you deploy locally( in remix)

Comment: @stofu what is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: transact to AB.Optimizer errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="0.5", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149043/discussion-between-rohan-nero-and-stofu).

Comment: ok.............

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Also, there is no floating point numbers here, `amount` is an uint. `ether` in solidity means  `* 10 ^ 18`, so your variable is effectively `10^17`

Comment: i deploy the contract on test net but its not sending eth and its also no meeting the condition of  require(amount >=0.1 ether,"transfer amount to low");

Comment: are  you actually sending ether in the tx? Or just setting amount to 0.1 ether and hoping it will work?

Comment: Oh it seems you figured it out with Rohan, all good :)