# How are discrepancies with integer division handled in production contracts?

Tags: solidity

In my Escrow contract I have an item worth

`0.1 ether` and `1 wei` =  100,000,000,000,000,00**1** wei.

I need to divide this amount in half, and send it to two people.

100,000,000,000,000,00**1** / 2

Each person would be receiving 50,000,000,000,000,000 and ignoring the `1 wei` because of the floor division in Solidity.

```
payable(user_one).transfer(50000000000000000);
payable(user_two).transfer(50000000000000000);
```

How is this issue handled in production? Is it ignored because of the insignificant amount being lost?

Comment: You might need to use a fixed-point math library. See: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83785/24693).